# how to set role in backand user signup

Tags: backand

I am able to singup user but cannot set role on the user signup.

here is json data I am using to singup.

```
let data = JSON.stringify({
      firstName: "first",
      lastName: "last",
      role : 'User',
      email: "first.last@gmail.com",
      password: "password",
      confirmPassword: "password",
      parameters:{
        phone: "0000000"
      }  
});
```

Thanx

Comment: what error you are getting ??

Comment: not getting error, I can signup fine but when I login to dashboard 'role' is blank and because its not set I cannot perform security on other objects

Comment: you saving these details in database ? whats in there

Comment: just want to make sure we are on same page, I am using https://www.backand.com/ for my  api.

Comment: when I use their 1/user/signup api I can register user fine but role parameter is not set. and yes I can save data to database fine without any issues problem is if role is not set on user account then I cannot restrict others from accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

This is already answered , please look here 
[How to use Backand Security Action Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780127/how-to-use-backand-security-action-parameters/38099045#38099045)